# Refile to non-agenda files

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-refile

Running Doom Emacs 2.0.9 on Emacs 27.1.

My current settings are:

```
(setq org-directory "~/Documents/organize/org-mode")
(setq org-agenda-files (directory-files-recursively "~/Documents/organize/org-mode/agenda"  "^[[:alnum:]].*\\.org\\'"))
```

`org-refile-targets` is set to:

```
((nil :maxlevel . 3)
 (org-agenda-files :maxlevel . 3))
```

Refile targets seem to come only from agenda files. I would like to be able to refile to any file in org directory.

What changes do I need to make?

Comment: You find a more elegant solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21335010/6700748

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc string for the variable `org-refile-targets` says:

> - a specification of the files to be considered, either a list of files,
>   or a symbol whose function or variable value will be used to retrieve
>   a file name or a list of file names.  If you use ‘org-agenda-files’ for
>   that, all agenda files will be scanned for targets.  Nil means consider
>   headings in the current buffer.

So you can define a variable whose value is a list of the filenames of interest or a function that returns that list and use it in defining a new entry for `org-refile-targets`.

Take the case of an org directory that contains a bunch of `.org` files (in a single level) that you want to be targets for refiling. Here's a function that returns a list of them:

```el
(defun ndk/org-refile-candidates ()
     (directory-files "/path/to/some/directory/org" t ".*\\.org$"))
```

You'll have to tweak the path according to your circumstances.

If the set of files is static, it might be easier to define a variable instead. If you want a recursive traversal, you'll need to modify the function accordingly.

Then you can add this to `org-refile-targets` with something like this:

```el
(add-to-list 'org-refile-targets '(ndk/org-refile-candidates :maxlevel . 3))
```

I should note that this is mostly untested, but it *should* work (ahem).

Comment: Thanks. Your solution did work, perfectly. The only change I did was to change the function to recursively traverse the directory. Here is how it looks now:

(defun ndk/org-refile-candidates ()
  (directory-files-recursively "~/Documents/organize/org-mode/"  "^[[:alnum:]].*\\.org\\'"))

Comment: Are the agenda files now included twice then? I don't know if that causes trouble, but if I were you, I'd try to avoid it.

Comment: I did not understand agenda files included twice. The documentation says: '(directory-files-recursively DIR REGEXP &optional INCLUDE-DIRECTORIES PREDICATE FOLLOW-SYMLINKS)'. I thought we were specifying only the DIR and the REGEXP.

Comment: I meant your setting of `org-refile-targets`: if you include both the new function *and* the old `org-agenda-files` entry, you'll get duplicate entries, because the recursive traversal in the new function will find the agenda files as well.

Comment: Oh OK. Is there a way to avoid it? By the way, I did not find any difficulty.

Comment: Set `org-refile-targets` to include just the `nil` and  the new function entries - leave out the old `org-agenda-files` entry. But if it doesn't cause difficulties, you might want to leave well enough alone.